# Simple grading system that uses fstream to store data locally

Tags: c++

This program uses `fstream` to store data in the form of text files and folders which allows you to:

- Create and delete report cards (which are folders)
- Create and delete subjects (which are the text files)
- Get reports for single subjects or report cards and display a final average

You can download the executable on GitHub [here](https://github.com/PeteMcGreete/GradingSystem) or you can use the source code down here:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <filesystem>
#include "dirent.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

//create a directory file and store the users directory in it for later use
std::string getUserDirectory() {
    std::string directory = "";
    if (!std::ifstream("userDirectory.txt")) {
        std::cout << "If you have gotten this message it means you have not specified a directory.\n";
        std::cout << "In order for this program to work you need to specify the directory in which you located the executable.\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter the executable using double back slashes. \n";
        std::cout << "An Example: C:\\\\Users\\User1\\\\Desktop\\\\R.C.S\\\\     <-- remember those last two \\\\ \n";
        std::cout << "Warning, if you screw this up, please delete the existing file created called userDirectory.txt and restart the program. \n";
        std::cout << "Directory: ";
        std::cin >> directory;

        std::ofstream dirFile;
        dirFile.open("userDirectory.txt", std::ios::app);

        dirFile << directory;
    }

    std::ifstream dirFile("userDirectory.txt");
    directory = "";
    if (!dirFile.is_open()) std::cerr << "Unable to open file.\n";
    dirFile >> directory;

    return directory;
}
//ask user for the report card and subject to make a final directory for file i/o
std::string generateDirectory() {
    // More on this later
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::ostringstream combinedDirectory;
    std::string chosenReportCard = "";
    std::string chosenSubject = "";

    std::cout << "\nEnter report card name: ";
    getline(std::cin, chosenReportCard);
    combinedDirectory << getUserDirectory() << chosenReportCard;
    std::cout << "\nEnter the subject: ";
    getline(std::cin, chosenSubject);

    // create a subject directory based on input from user to enter grades into
    combinedDirectory << "\\" << chosenSubject << ".txt";
    std::string subjectDir = combinedDirectory.str();

    return subjectDir;
}
//template 1 called the 'regular'
static const std::string template1[] = { "Physical Education",
"Technology/Engineer", "Language Arts",
"Math", "Social Studies", "Science"

};
//template 2 called the 'mathematician'
static const std::string template2[] = { "Math", "Science", "Technology",
"Programming" };
//template 3 called the 'philosopher'
static const std::string template3[] = { "Art", "Social Studies",
"Language Arts", "Philosophy",

"Medieval World Studies" };

//allows users to add subjects themsevles and name them or use one of the tempates above
void addSubjects(int choice, std::string reportCardName) {
    if (choice == 1) {
        std::cout << "Input the number of subjects you would like to add: ";
        int numSubjects = 0;
        std::cin >> numSubjects;
        std::cout << "\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < numSubjects; i++) {
            std::cout << "Input the name of subject " << i+1 << ": ";
            std::string subject = "";
            std::cin >> subject;
            std::ostringstream path;
            path << getUserDirectory() << reportCardName << "\\" << subject << ".txt";
            std::string saveLocation = path.str();
            std::ofstream outfile(saveLocation.c_str());
            std::cout << subject << " is now a subject!" << std::endl;
        }
    } 
    else if (choice == 2) {
        std::cout << "Choose a template:\n";
        std::cout << "1)The Regular (all the basics, P.E, Math, Science etc.)\n";
        std::cout << "2)The Mathematician (Math, Science, Tech etc.)\n";
        std::cout << "3)The Philosopher (Social Studies, Language Arts, Art etc.)\n";
        std::cout << "More Coming Soon!\n";
        std::cout << "Template Selected: ";
        std::cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:

            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                std::ostringstream path;
                path << getUserDirectory() << reportCardName << "\\" << template1[i] << ".txt";
                std::string saveLocation = path.str();
                std::ofstream outfile(saveLocation.c_str());
                std::cout << "\n" << template1[i] << " Is now a subject!";
            }
            break;

        case 2:

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                std::ostringstream path;
                path << getUserDirectory() << reportCardName << "\\" << template2[i] << ".txt";
                std::string saveLocation = path.str();
                std::ofstream outfile(saveLocation.c_str());
                std::cout << "\n" << template2[i] << " Is now a subject!";
            }

            break;

        case 3:

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                std::ostringstream path;
                path << getUserDirectory() << reportCardName << "\\" << template3[i] << ".txt";
                std::string saveLocation = path.str();
                std::ofstream outfile(saveLocation.c_str());
                std::cout << "\n" << template3[i] << " Is now a subject!";
            }

            break;
        }
    }

}

//allows user to add subjects to an already existing report card
void addNewSubjects() {
        std::cin.ignore();
        int choice = 0;
        std::string reportCardName;
        std::cout << "\nEnter report card name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, reportCardName);

        int newSubjectAmount = 0;
        std::cout << "Input amount of new subjects to be created: ";
        std::cin >> newSubjectAmount;

        for (int i = 0; i < newSubjectAmount; i++) {
            std::cout << "Input the name of subject " << i + 1 << ": ";
            std::string newSubject = "";
            std::cin >> newSubject;
            std::ostringstream path;
            path << getUserDirectory() << reportCardName << "\\" << newSubject << ".txt";
            std::string saveLocation = path.str();
            std::ofstream outfile(saveLocation.c_str());
            std::cout << newSubject << " is now a subject!" << std::endl;
        }
}

//for generating a folder to store subjects 
void generateReportCard() {
    std::cin.ignore();
    int choice = 0;
    std::string reportCardName;
    std::cout << "\nEnter report card name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, reportCardName);
    _mkdir(reportCardName.c_str());  // make folder for report card
    std::cout << "\nYou successfully made a report card!\n";
    std::cout << "Would you like to:\n";
    std::cout << "1)Add subjects to it\n";
    std::cout << "2)Use a template?\n";
    std::cout << "(note you can only do this once)\n";
    std::cout << "1 or 2: ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::cout << "\n";
    addSubjects(choice, reportCardName);
}

//enables user to edit subjects and add assignments + grades into subject txt file
void enterGrades(int scoresToEnter) {
    std::ofstream subject;
    subject.open(generateDirectory().c_str(), std::ios::app);
    std::cout << "\nWarning! Please only enter grades based on percentage out of 100 (please don't use %'s)\n";
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue.\n";
    std::cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < scoresToEnter; ++i) {
        std::string assignmentName = "";
        std::cout << "\nEnter assignment name: ";
        getline(std::cin, assignmentName);

        std::string grade = "";
        std::cout << "\nEnter grade: ";
        getline(std::cin, grade);

        std::string subjectEntry = assignmentName + " " + grade;

        subject << subjectEntry << std::endl;
    }
}

// calculate subject card average and display it
void printSubject() {
    std::ifstream subject(generateDirectory().c_str());

    if (!subject.is_open()) std::cerr << "Unable to open file.\n";

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> assignmentList = {};
    std::vector<double> gradeList = {};
    std::string assignmentName = "";
    double score = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while (subject >> assignmentName >> score) {
        assignmentList.push_back(assignmentName);
        gradeList.push_back(score);
        avg += score;
        assignmentName = "";
        counter++;
    }

    avg = avg / counter;
    std::cout << "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < assignmentList.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "Assignment: " << assignmentList[i] << " || Score " << gradeList[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "\n------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Average grade is: " << avg;
    std::cout << "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
}

//gives a report of the entire report card
void giveReport() {
    std::cout << "\nNote that subjects must have atleast 1 assignment minimum to give final report.\n\n";
    std::string reportCardName = "";
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << "Enter name of report card: ";
    getline(std::cin, reportCardName);
    std::ostringstream path;
    path << getUserDirectory() << reportCardName;
    std::string location = path.str();

    std::vector<std::string> fileNames = {};
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir(location.c_str())) != NULL) {
        int counter = 0;
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if (counter > 1) fileNames.push_back(ent->d_name);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    std::string tempLocation;
    double score;
    double avg;
    int avgIterator;
    double totalAvg = 0;
    int totalAvgIterator = 0;
    std::string ignoreName = "";
    std::cout << "\n------------------\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.size(); i++) {
        tempLocation = "";
        std::ostringstream tempPath;

        tempPath << getUserDirectory() << reportCardName << "\\" << fileNames[i];
        tempLocation = tempPath.str();

        score = 0;
        avg = 0;
        avgIterator = 0;

        std::ifstream subject(tempLocation.c_str());
        if (!subject.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to open file " << tempLocation << " to read from\n";
            continue;
        }

        while (subject >> ignoreName >> score) {
            avg += score;
            totalAvg += score;
            avgIterator++;
            totalAvgIterator++;
            ignoreName = "";
        }

        avg = avg / avgIterator;
        std::cout << "\nSubject: " << fileNames[i] << " || Average score: " << avg;

        subject.close();
        subject.clear();
    }
    totalAvg = totalAvg / totalAvgIterator;
    std::cout << "\n------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Total average grade is: " << totalAvg;
    std::cout << "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";

    closedir(dir);
}

//allows user to delete a single subject and all it's data
void deleteSubject() {
    std::string reportCardName = "";
    std::string subjectName = "";

    std::cout << "\nEnter the name report card where the subject is located: ";
    std::cin >> reportCardName;
    std::cout << "\nEnter the name of the subject: ";
    std::cin >> subjectName;

    std::ostringstream path;
    path << getUserDirectory() << reportCardName << "\\" << subjectName << ".txt";
    std::string subjectLocation = path.str();

    if (remove(subjectLocation.c_str()) != 0) std::cout << "\nError, could not delete file.\n";
    else std::cout << "\n" << subjectName << " Succsessfully deleted!\n";

}
//credits to stack overflow for providing me with this function that doesn't force me to use boost
int DeleteDirectory(const std::string &refcstrRootDirectory,
    bool              bDeleteSubdirectories = true)
{
    bool            bSubdirectory = false;       // Flag, indicating whether
                                                 // subdirectories have been found
    HANDLE          hFile;                       // Handle to directory
    std::string     strFilePath;                 // Filepath
    std::string     strPattern;                  // Pattern
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FileInformation;             // File information


    strPattern = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\*.*";
    hFile = ::FindFirstFile(strPattern.c_str(), &FileInformation);
    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if (FileInformation.cFileName[0] != '.')
            {
                strFilePath.erase();
                strFilePath = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\" + FileInformation.cFileName;

                if (FileInformation.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                {
                    if (bDeleteSubdirectories)
                    {
                        // Delete subdirectory
                        int iRC = DeleteDirectory(strFilePath, bDeleteSubdirectories);
                        if (iRC)
                            return iRC;
                    }
                    else
                        bSubdirectory = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Set file attributes
                    if (::SetFileAttributes(strFilePath.c_str(),
                        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL) == FALSE)
                        return ::GetLastError();

                    // Delete file
                    if (::DeleteFile(strFilePath.c_str()) == FALSE)
                        return ::GetLastError();
                }
            }
        } while (::FindNextFile(hFile, &FileInformation) == TRUE);

        // Close handle
        ::FindClose(hFile);

        DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
        if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
            return dwError;
        else
        {
            if (!bSubdirectory)
            {
                // Set directory attributes
                if (::SetFileAttributes(refcstrRootDirectory.c_str(),
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL) == FALSE)
                    return ::GetLastError();

                // Delete directory
                if (::RemoveDirectory(refcstrRootDirectory.c_str()) == FALSE)
                    return ::GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
//allows user to delete a report card with all it's subjects using the function above
void deleteReportCard() {
    std::string reportCardName = "";
    std::cout << "Enter report card name: ";
    std::cin >> reportCardName;

    std::ostringstream path; 
    path << getUserDirectory() << reportCardName;
    std::string location = path.str();

    int iRC = 0;

    iRC = DeleteDirectory(location);

    if (iRC){
        std::cout << "Error " << iRC << std::endl;
    }

}

//main menu giving access to all the functions above
void mainMenu() {
    std::cout << "\nPlease select an option below\n";
    std::cout << "1) Create a report card or create more subjects\n";
    std::cout << "2) Enter grades into a subject\n";
    std::cout << "3) Get a report for a report card and/or subject\n";
    std::cout << "4) Delete a report card or subject\n";
    std::cout << "Option Selected: ";

    int choice = 0;
    std::cin >> choice;

    // check for user choice then execute a function based on that choice
    int numAssignments = 0;
    std::string giveNewReport;
    std::string printNewSubject;
    std::string runAgain;
    std::string subjectDelete = "";
    std::string reportCardDelete = "";
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        choice = 0;
        std::cout << "\nSelect an option below\n";
        std::cout << "1) Create a report card then add subjects too it\n";
        std::cout << "2) Add subjects to an existing report card\n";
        std::cout << "Choice: ";
        std::cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1) {
            for (;;) {
                generateReportCard();
                std::cout << "\n\nWould you like to create another report card? (y/n): ";
                runAgain = "";
                std::cin >> runAgain;
                if (runAgain != "y") break;
            }
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            for (;;) {
                addNewSubjects();
                std::cout << "\n\nWould you like to add more subjects to another report card? (y/n): ";
                runAgain = "";
                std::cin >> runAgain;
                if (runAgain != "y") break;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "How many scored assignments would you like to enter? ";
        std::cin >> numAssignments;
        enterGrades(numAssignments);

        break;

    case 3:
        choice = 0;
        std::cout << "\nSelect an option below\n";
        std::cout << "1) Disply the average for every subject in a report card and a final average\n";
        std::cout << "2) Display the average for only 1 subject\n";
        std::cout << "Choice: ";
        std::cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1) {
            for (;;) {
                giveReport();
                giveNewReport = "";
                std::cout << "Would you like to get a report from another report "
                    "card? (y/n):";
                std::cin >> giveNewReport;
                if (giveNewReport != "y") break;
            }

        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            for (;;) {
                printSubject();
                printNewSubject = "";
                std::cout << "Would you like to print out another subject? (y/n):";
                std::cin >> printNewSubject;
                if (printNewSubject != "y") break;
            }
            if (choice != 1 && choice != 2) std::cout << "Error, that is not a valid choice. \n";
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        choice = 0;
        std::cout << "\nSelect an option below\n";
        std::cout << "1) Delete a subject\n";
        std::cout << "2) Delete a report card\n";
        std::cout << "Choice: ";
        std::cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1) {
            for (;;) {
                deleteSubject();
                subjectDelete = "";
                std::cout << "Would you like to delete another subject? (y/n): ";
                std::cin >> subjectDelete;

                if (subjectDelete != "y") break;

            }

        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            for (;;) {
                deleteReportCard();
                reportCardDelete = "";
                std::cout << "Would you like to delete another report card? (y/n): ";
                std::cin >> reportCardDelete;

                if (reportCardDelete != "y") break;
            }

            if (choice != 1 && choice != 2) std::cout << "Error, that is not a valid choice. \n";

            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    getUserDirectory();
    for (;;) {
        mainMenu();
        std::string backToMainMenu = "";
        std::cout << "Return back to main menu? n will shutdown the program (y/n): ";
        std::cin >> backToMainMenu;
        if (backToMainMenu != "y") break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review.  What things are you looking for from the review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some room for improvement in this code. Below I have enlisted comments that I believe your code could benefit from:

1. Use enum class instead of raw integers for the `choice` variable within
   the `addSubject()` function since now it's not immediately clear
   what option each case refers to. Also it reduces the risk of error and makes input sanitizing easier as by using enums you are constraining the range of values passed to the function. Also see the point mentioning magic numbers.
2. Don't put your functions/classes/variables etc. within the global namespace. Create your own and put them inside to avoid possible name clashes. Namespaces are also important if you are using templates heavily (you don't right now, but it's yet another reason to make it a habit to use your own namespace).
3. You are using a lot of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) that make it harder to understand the code, for example:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) // what is 5? Why 5 and not e.g. 6?
```

It is a good practice to use a named variable instead, whose name would explain what this value is. It's also good to comment why this particular value has been chosen if the name itself can't explain it fully.

4. You are mixing responsibilities within your functions. Almost all your functions handle user interaction, operation on files and internal program logic in the same time, whereas their names suggest that they handle only one of these things (and in fact they should handle only one of them). For example, looking at the signature of the function `getUserDirectory()` most people would expect that it takes the directory name and returns it as string, but this function, apart from doing what the name suggests, also has some unexpected side effect, which is creating a file and writing to it. The code related to file handling should be moved to a separate function - that way not only is your program structure cleaner and easier to debug, but it's easy to imagine that you may want to reuse the function that writes text to a file later in various contexts. Also, if you realise that your approach towards file handling needs improvement, you won't have to correct your code in multiple places, which makes the code easier to manage.
5. The previous point leads to a conclusion that you should separate functions responsible for user interaction from functions handling internal program logic. Apart from easier code management and development, this makes your program more versatile, enabling you to use it with different libraries.
6. Why not name `template1[]`, `template2[]` and `template3[]` in a way that explains their context, e.g. `regular_template[]`, `mathematician_template[]`, `philosopher_template[]`? That way you don't have to explain it in the comments, and it's instantly clear what they are for when someone sees them used in the code, whereas right now it's necessary to go to their declaration and read the comments.
7. Use clearer function names. For example, ideally it should be clear what the `giveReport()` function does just by reading its name, and I don't know if "give" in this context is about writing the report to a file, printing it to console or saving it to some variable to be used further within the program. The comment above the function doesn't explain it either.
8. Group your headers with respect to the functionality they refer to - it's easier to identify unused dependencies that way. If you have headers placed in no particular order, it's easy to just forget about one that you don't use as it "blends in". It's also clearer that way which libraries you use for a particular feature.
9. Make the functions as stand-alone as possible. Right now you are making assumptions within function bodies about the activites performed before the function was called - it is best avoided. For instance, some of your functions begin with the line `std::cin.ignore()` as they assume someone had hit "enter" after providing some input and before they were called. It's not these functions' responsibility to care about this - the function using `std::cin` for input earlier should clean after itself with that line. By composing functions the way you do now, you are significantly limiting the context in which they can be used - what if you change your program flow and decide to use some of them before the user enters some input? What if you decide to read the input with `std::getline()` instead of `std::cin::operator>>`? The input becomes corrupted as `std::cin.ignore()` would "eat" one character. This opens many possibilites for hard-to-track bugs.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the time you took to write this.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you find it helpful.